# Data returns null when retrieving from a firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, crud

I am trying currently trying to create a CRUD Contacts Application using react. I'm currently having a problem on pulling user details through my database. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ContactDetails = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const { contactId } = params;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://MY-DB.firebaseio.com/contacts/${contactId}.json`
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, [contactId]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>CONTACT DETAIL</h1>
      <p>{params.contactId}</p>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ContactDetails;
```

But trying to log the data results in `null`.

Here is my database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry4FE.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add a catch block after your last `.then()` and do a console log on the err object to see if it gives you more information.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Fortunately I was able to find the problem, my call for that page contained a ':' in the link so instead of contactID being the 'SOME-ID', it was ':SOME-ID' thus not referring to any key in my DB.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!